# How to concatenate two registers in assembly? SPARC

Tags: assembly, multiplication, sparc

I want two registers to be combined as one unit. I am learning new multiplication by adding and shifting. So is this a wrong way to do?

```
1stmul:
        set     0x04ee67b7,     %l1     !multiplicand 
        set     0x072e8b8c,     %l2     !multiplier
        clr     %l0                     !product      
        addx    %l0, %l2, %l2           !combining two units?
```

Comment: sorry, a register. product and multiplier registers combined as a unit

Comment: how do you want them combined, and why?

Comment: I have an algorithm to implement -

 negative = multiplier >= 0 ? 0 : 1;
product = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
if (multiplier & 1)
product += multiplicand;
(product and multiplier registers combined as a unit) >> 1;
}
if (negative)
product -= multiplicand;

And I have to write that in assembly. The multiplication method to use is shift and add. And I know that the product and the multiplier have to be combined together.

Comment: then why not just write it in C and compile it?

Comment: Because this is my homework assignment, I am suppose to write it in assembly, using the shift and add method..

Comment: Ohh thanks I will check this one out